# when Virtual installation of Flow-project (using docker containers). the default password password

Tags: ubuntu, flow-project

To install a containerized Flow stack, run:

docker run -d -p 5901:5901 -p 6901:6901 fywu85/flow-desktop:latest
To access the docker container, go to the following URL and enter the default password password:

http://localhost:6901/vnc.html
To use the Jupyter Notebook inside the container, run:

jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1

---

what is the    default password password:

Answer (score 0):

The default password is password.

That's it. The literal string "password".